# How can I iterate through an unknown number of models and compare data in that model to another model in a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So here's the situation.  I am new to MVC and I am looking for the simplest way to go about Iterating through an unknown number of one model to continually look for the highest integer value of one property of that model based on data from another model.

To give you a better idea, here's some background:
I have an application set up to allow a user to choose 1, 2, 3, or 4.  Once a number has been chosen, the application must then search through an unknown number of models which have different integer values for 1, 2, 3, 4.  Model one might have 6, 8, 7, 2 and model two might have 9, 7, 6, 3.  I need to first read in the 1, 2, 3, or 4 from the first model and then based on that selection (let's say 2) examine each instance of the other model for column 2 looking for the highest value (in this example that would be 8 coming from the second model's second example).

In this example, this is the first model which determines which column will be examined:

```
public class Input
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool GreenCircle { get; set; }
    public bool BlueSquare { get; set; }
    public bool BlackDiamond { get; set; }
    public bool TerrainPark { get; set; }
}
```

This is the second model which will have an unknown number of them as I want the ability to add and delete Resorts at any time:

```
public class Resort
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int BlackDiamond { get; set; }
    public int BlueSquare { get; set; }
    public int GreenCircle { get; set; }
    public int TerrainPark { get; set; }
}
```

So a user will choose BlackDiamond, then the application must search through each Resort Model to find the one with the highest value in the BlackDiamond property.

My idea so far was to have a controller that has the DBContext for both models but I do not know how to properly iterate through an unknown number of the second model.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean 'Unknown number of models'. Are you using random? Also, some code would be nice.

Comment: What I mean is that the number of models can change at any time.  I will edit in the code to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Paul's answer, but using your classes:

```
List<Resort> resorts = GetResortsFromDatabase();
if (input.BlackDiamond)
{
    return resorts.OrderByDescending(x => x.BlackDiamond).First();
}
else if (input.BlueSquare)
{
    return resorts.OrderByDescending(x => x.BlueSquare).First();
}
// etc...
```

If you need more complicated logic, you could instead use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var resort in GetResortsFromDatabase())
{
    if (input.BlackDiamond && resort.BlackDiamond > 5) 
    {
        DoSomething(input, resort); // This will do something to the input and each resort.
    }
}
```

If you need help writing the `GetResortsFromDatabase()` function, then you need to ask a question like "How do I get multiple records from my database" and tell us how you're talking to the database. (Linq2Sql? Entity Framework? Something else?).

Comment: I would be using Entity Framework and yea I would probably need help writing the GetResortsFromDatabase() function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure others will do better, but could something like this fit the bill?

```
class MyModel
{
    public int[] PropertyValues = new int[4];
}

class Main
{
    IEnumerable<MyModel> models;

    public void MyFunc()
    {
        var models = new List<MyModel>();

        models.Add(new MyModel() { PropertyValues = new int[] { 6, 8, 7, 2 } });
        models.Add(new MyModel() { PropertyValues = new int[] { 9, 7, 6, 3 } });

        var index = 1;

        var maxValue = models.Max(m => m.PropertyValues[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this fits the bill.  The models already exist with the data in them, I am trying to gain access to both models and every iteration of the model which has the integer values that need compared and that should be an unknown number of models as it can change.

Comment: aren't the models already contained in some `IEnumerable` that you can `Max` over? If not, how do you know how many there are at runtime?

Comment: No I haven't contained them in any IEnumerable, should I have?  How could I do that? Sorry, really new to MVC.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface provided by the framework; it doesn't really have anything to do specifically with MVC.

Comment: OP states that he has 'an unknown number of models'. Unless they are in some container class, then how will they be able to reference them at all?